# How to store and manage test data in a CI project without polluting the code repository?

Tags: unit-testing, github, amazon-s3, gitlab-ci, github-actions

I am setting up a test scheme for a product that is data-hungry. The goal is to have a basic set of unit tests for c++/cuda code running within a Github repo, and also to make them self-hostable.

The sparse set of cowboy-coded tests that I have inherited have big(~20 MB) binary data files stuffed into the github repo, which hurts my heart. We have a snazzy Amazon S3 data  repository.

I could hand-cut a bespoke solution, but I don't have the rest of my life to do it.

How have others intelligently structured their tests to handle this?

The tests as they exist store data in the code repo.

Possible cuts:

- each test checks for data in a data/ folder and wgets it if it isn't there (will github handle this?)
- have a data/ folder that is soft-mapped (how?) to the S3 repo

etc., etc.

Comment: I'd either store it in a different repo that is clearly labeled, or put in in blob storage, or put it in GitLFS, to keep it outside of the git commands and keep them fast.